# merging two folder with mod-rewrite in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm currently developing a drupal based website but will have to keep a legacy system and many static pages/folders alive. It would be great if i could keep the old rubble in a separate folder than the new site. This would mean I've to merge both folders on the fly. I thought that this folder structure would be great.

```
/htdocs/legacy (symlink to old web root)
/htdocs/index.php
/htdocs/.htaccess
/htdocs/other drupal files and folders 
/htdocs/...
```

This would mean that if i.e. mydomain.com/xyz.php is accessed the server should try to serve it in the following order.

1. if file or folder in /htdocs/ server this
2. if file or folder in /legacy/ serve this but do not rewrite the browsers location bar.
3. else rewrite pass it as querystring to the

I came up with the following rewrite rules. Which however don't work. I can either serve files in legacy or via drupal.

```
# 1. server from .htaccess folder

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule  ^(.*)$  -  [NC,L]

# 2. serve from legacy

RewriteCond  /full-path-to-legacy-folder/%{REQUEST_URI}  -f [OR]
RewriteCond  /full-path-to-legacy-folder/%{REQUEST_URI}  -d
RewriteRule  ^(.*)$  /legacy/$1  [NC,L]

# 3. else

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Has anyone of you suggestions?

Many thanks!

Comment: Looks about right - what exactly doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're just rewriting the URL, and there are other operations that need to be done with the file (like `mod_php`), try changing your `[L]` options to `[PT]` to allow regular processing to continue on the request.